# New to Hadoop and dumbo, how to correctly sequence these operations?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Consider the following log file format:

```
id        v1        v2        v3
1         15        30        25
2         10        10        20
3         50        30        30
```

We are to calculate the *average value frequency (AVF)* for each data row on a Hadoop cluster using dumbo. AVF for a data point with m attributes is defined as:

```
avf = (1/m)* sum (frequencies of attributes 1..m)
```

so for the first row, avf = (1/3)*(1+2+1) ~= 1.33. An outlier is identified by a low AVF.

#### Programming problem

We have the following pseudo/python code:

```
H = {}  # stores attribute frequencies

map1(_, datapoint): # 
  for attr in datapoint.attrs:
    yield (attr, 1)

reduce1(attr, values):
  H[attr] = sum(values)

map2(_, datapoint):
  sum = 0
  m = len(datapoint.attrs)
  for attr in datapoint.attrs:
    sum += H[attr]        

  yield (1/m)*sum, datapoint

reduce2(avf, datapoints): # identity reducer, only sorts datapoints on avf
  yield avf, datapoints
```

Problem is, how do we plug our set of data points into both `map1` and `map2`, as well as use the intermediary hash `H` in map2. Having `H` globally defined as above seems like going against the MapReduce concept.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the first step is to calculate a histogram:

```
[attr, value] => frequency
```

where `frequency` is the number of times that `value` ocurred in the `attr` column.

The next step is to take the histogram table and the original data, for each line calculate the AVF, and sort them.

I'd do it in two passes: one map-reduce pass to calculate the histogram, a second m-r pass to find the AVF using the histogram.  I'd also use a single constant hash guilt-free, as getting the histogram values and the cell values to the same locality will be a messy beast.  (For example, have map1 emit `[attr val id]` with `[attr val]` as key; and have reduce1 accumulate all records for each key, count them, and emit `[id attr val count]`.  The second pass uses `id` as key to reassemble and then average each row).

---

To calculate a histogram, it helps to think of the middle step as 'group' rather than 'sort'. Here's how: since the reduce input is sorted by key, have it accumulate all records for the given key, and as soon as it sees a different key, emit the count. Wukong, the ruby equivalent of dumbo, has an `Accumulator`, and I assume dumbo does too. (See below for working code).

This leaves you with

```
attr1    val1a      frequency
attr1    val1b      frequency
attr2    val2a      frequency
...
attrN    attrNz     frequency
```

For the next pass, I'd load that data into a hash table -- a simple `Hash` (`dictionary`) if it fits in memory, a fast key-value store if not -- and calculate each record's AVF just as you had it.

---

Here is working ruby code to calculate the avf; see http://github.com/mrflip/wukong/blob/master/examples/stats/avg_value_frequency.rb

### First Pass

```
module AverageValueFrequency
  # Names for each column's attribute, in order
  ATTR_NAMES = %w[length width height]

  class HistogramMapper < Wukong::Streamer::RecordStreamer
    def process id, *values
      ATTR_NAMES.zip(values).each{|attr, val| yield [attr, val] }
    end
  end

  #
  # For an accumulator, you define a key that is used to group records
  #
  # The Accumulator calls #start! on the first record for that group,
  # then calls #accumulate on all records (including the first).
  # Finally, it calls #finalize to emit a result for the group.
  #
  class HistogramReducer < Wukong::Streamer::AccumulatingReducer
    attr_accessor :count

    # use the attr and val as the key
    def get_key attr, val, *_
      [attr, val]
    end

    # start the sum with 0 for each key
    def start! *_
      self.count = 0
    end
    # ... and count the number of records for this key
    def accumulate *_
      self.count += 1
    end
    # emit [attr, val, count]
    def finalize
      yield [key, count].flatten
    end
  end
end

Wukong::Script.new(AverageValueFrequency::HistogramMapper, AverageValueFrequency::HistogramReducer).run
```

---

### Second pass

```
module AverageValueFrequency
  class AvfRecordMapper < Wukong::Streamer::RecordStreamer
    # average the frequency of each value
    def process id, *values
      sum = 0.0
      ATTR_NAMES.zip(values).each do |attr, val|
        sum += histogram[ [attr, val] ].to_i
      end
      avf = sum / ATTR_NAMES.length.to_f
      yield [id, avf, *values]
    end

    # Load the histogram from a tab-separated file with
    #   attr    val   freq
    def histogram
      return @histogram if @histogram
      @histogram = { }
      File.open(options[:histogram_file]).each do |line|
        attr, val, freq = line.chomp.split("\t")
        @histogram[ [attr, val] ] = freq
      end
      @histogram
    end
  end
end
```